How to specify current frame in file path
I'm having an issue where I need to read image sequences and UDIMs at the same time.
The UDIM can be specified in brackets <like this> (given that the mode is set to UDIM Tiles):

Is there a way I can add the current frame number to this expression? In Houdini, you can just do $F to get the current frame number.
In some areas of Blender, I've seen people use #Frame, but I can't see how that would apply here.
Thanks!
Anson
